# unzipped in target directory

Tags: android, unzip

I want to unzip to zip file in same directory,When I try below code it unzipped below target directory not in target folder,how can I unzipped all files in target directory in android

```
public static void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDir) {
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;

    File dest_file = new File(destDir);
    //dest_file.mkdirs(); // creates if destination directory not existed

    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream));
        ZipEntry zipEntry;

        while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            String zipEntryName = zipEntry.getName();
            File file = new File(destDir + zipEntryName);

            if (file.exists()) {

            } else if (zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            } else {
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream, 1024);
                int count;

                while ((count = zipInputStream.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                    bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                bufferedOutputStream.flush();
                bufferedOutputStream.close();
            }
        }
        zipInputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);
    }

}
```

I call unzip File

```
 String source = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.kocsistem.pixageoneandroid/files/Contents/widgetContent  + "/" + "123.zip";
 String target = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.kocsistem.pixageoneandroid/files/Contents/widgetContent ;
 Utils.unzip(source, target);
```

Comment: I added in code

Comment: You say 'below target directory'. But in which folder exactly?

Comment: `File file = new File(destDir + zipEntryName);` That should be `File file = new File(destDir +"/" + zipEntryName);` as i suppose that that name will not start with a '/'.

Comment: gives error:  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.kocsistem.pixageoneandroid/files/Contents/widgetContent/css/foundation.css (Not a directory)

Comment: destFilePath:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.kocsistem.pixageoneandroid/files/Contents/widgetContent

Comment: without extra  "/" landed below my target folder, not inside,it unzipped correctly but I want to landed in target folder,When we try File file = new File(destDir +"/" + zipEntryName) it try unzipped foundation.css file and it gives error,because its not folder

Comment: `without extra "/" landed below my target folder, ` Yes i already knew that. You told that before. But i asked for the full path of that folder. Why dont you tell?

Comment: Empty the target folder as whith all your experiments you could have created a directory for a file.

Comment: I added in code

Comment: They land in the `Contents` folder? And all filenames start with `widgetContent......`?